# Create a value whose data type name is described in a string

Tags: haskell

Is is possible to create in Haskell a value whose data type name is described a string? It is similar to what the  `newInstance` method of `Class` class in Java does.

Here's an Example. Suppose the data:

```
data Person = Person {name::String}
```

I want to create a value of Person similar to this:

```
let myPerson = create "Person"
```

, where `create` function creates a value of `Pearson` with the `name` field empty.

I want that the `create` function can do this with any data. So, i dont want something static.

Is this possible?

Comment: Nope, this is definitely impossible with Haskell.  Haskell is very strictly typesafe: what type would `myPerson` have at compile time?

Comment: What use case do you have for this?  Why not just make a data type that has an extra `typeName` field?

Comment: If your instance is Typeable you can get the type of a value as a string. `show $ typeOf "Hey" ===> "[Char]"`, but trying to implement the factory pattern in Haskell means you probably shouldn't be writing Java in Haskell. You could pattern match on that value, but I would rethink what you are trying to do in terms of Haskell. You could use TemplateHaskell, but that is a compile-time only solution.

Comment: Interpreting it quite, quite loosely, you might be interested in Data.Default.

Comment: Dynamic typing is a world of runtime error pain. Choose what should be allowed, check the data as it comes in, and act appropriately, instead of handing the user the keys to the program with your do-anything-you-like `create` function.

Answer (score 1):

Loosely speaking, yes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Dynamic

data Person = Person { personName :: String }
  deriving (Show, Typeable)

data Cat = Cat { catName :: String }
  deriving (Show, Typeable)

create :: String -> Dynamic
create "Person" = toDyn Person { personName = "" }
create "Cat" = toDyn Cat { catName = "" }
create other = error $ "Cannot create " ++ other

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let myPerson = (create "Person") { personName = "Bill" }
  print (fromDynamic myPerson)
```

You can also use `Data.Default` for defaulting all fields so some reasonable value. But it seems like a bad idea to do this with a set of unrelated types. If you’re doing it with different constructors of an ADT, then what you’ve got is the basis of a parser for that data type, which only parses the constructor. For example:

```
data Housemate
  = Person { name :: String }
  | Cat { name :: String }
  | Dog { name :: String }

create :: String -> String -> Housemate  -- No longer dynamic.
create "Person" = Person
create "Cat" = Cat
create "Dog" = Dog
```

You probably want to take a different approach, though. Haskell does not work well with dynamic typing. If you provide more information about the actual problem you’re trying to solve, you will attract better answers.

Comment: This answer is not exactly what I want, because the types that can be created in 'create' function are defined statically.
But this response was important to me because I did not know the type 'Dynamic'. Since then, I began to study it, and it spawned a doubt. Im going to add a new question to describe my doubt.